# Can't get an Entry object which is a fraction

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
import fractions

def tests(parameters, root):
    print(parameters[0])
    root.destroy()
    return None

class ScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, vertical=True, horizontal=False):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # canvas for inner frame
        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self._canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news') # changed

        # create right scrollbar and connect to canvas Y
        self._vertical_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self._canvas.yview)
        if vertical:
            self._vertical_bar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self._canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self._vertical_bar.set)

        # create bottom scrollbar and connect to canvas X
        self._horizontal_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', command=self._canvas.xview)
        if horizontal:
            self._horizontal_bar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
        self._canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self._horizontal_bar.set)

        # inner frame for widgets
        self.inner = tk.Frame(self._canvas)
        self._window = self._canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.inner, anchor='nw')

        # autoresize inner frame
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # changed
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) # changed

        # resize when configure changed
        self.inner.bind('<Configure>', self.resize)

        # resize inner frame to canvas size
        self.resize_width = False
        self.resize_height = False
        self._canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.inner_resize)

    def resize(self, event=None): 
        self._canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._canvas.bbox('all'))

    def inner_resize(self, event):
        # resize inner frame to canvas size
        if self.resize_width:
            self._canvas.itemconfig(self._window, width=event.width)
        if self.resize_height:
            self._canvas.itemconfig(self._window, height=event.height)


def interface(root):
    global parameters
    # create scrolled frame
    sf = ScrolledFrame(root, True, True)
    sf.pack(fill='both', expand=True) # resize with window

    entries= []

    tk.Label(sf.inner, text="a").grid(row=2, sticky='w')
    entry=tk.Entry(sf.inner)
    entries.append(entry)
    entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

    tk.Label(sf.inner, text="b").grid(row=3, sticky='w')
    entry=tk.Entry(sf.inner)
    entries.append(entry)
    entry.grid(row=3, column=1)

    def get():
        parameters=[]
        temp=[]
        temp.append(float(entries[0].get()))
        temp.append(round(float(fractions.Fraction(entries[1].get())), 7))
        parameters=temp

    bouton_Valider =tk.Button(sf.inner, text="Valider les paramètres", fg="blue", command=get)
    bouton_Valider.grid(row=4, column=1)

    bouton_Executer = tk.Button(sf.inner, text="Exécuter le programme", fg="red", command=lambda: tests(parameters, root))
    bouton_Executer.grid(row=5, column=1)

    root.mainloop() 

    return parameters
```

For the Entry 'b' , I want the user to enter a fraction like '4000/(60*60*1000)'. I tried to get this entry with the instruction:"round(float(fractions.Fraction(entries[1].get())), 7)", but after entering the values 'a' and 'b', and clicking on the "Valider les paramètres" button, I get the error:"ValueError: Invalid literal for Fraction: '4000/(60*10*100)' ". As a result of this, when I click the "Exécuter le programme" button, I get the error:"name 'parameters' is not defined"

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: again the same problem with `parameters` - you have to use `global` in all  functions in which you assign value to `parameters` - it means in `get()`. And it is good to assign default value outside functions - if you don't press `Valider les paramètres` then it will not run `get()` which create `parameters` (because it doesn't before - you didn't assign any value to variable before) and then other button can't get not-existing `parameters` - and you get error.

Comment: for `Fraction` it is a string `"4000/(60*60*1000)"` - `Fraction( "4000/(60*60*1000)" )`, not expression which Python will calculate before it uses result in `Fraction`. You would have to use `eval()` and Python will run it as Python's code and it will calculate value before it will put result in `Fraction` - `Fraction( eval("4000/(60*60*1000)") )`

Answer (score 1):

For `Fraction` it is a string `"4000/(60*60*1000)"`

```
import fractions 

print(fractions.Fraction( "4000/(60*60*1000)" ))

# Error
```

not expression which Python will calculate and `Fraction` will use its result.

You would have to use `eval()` and Python will run it as Python's code and it will calculate value before it will put result in Fraction

```
import fractions 

print(fractions.Fraction( eval("4000/(60*60*1000)") ))

# OK
```

But it seems you don't need `Fraction()` but only `eval()

```
parameters.append(round( eval(entries[1].get()), 7))
```

---

As for `parameters` - you have to use `global` in `get()` to inform function that it has to assign value to external variable `parameters` instead of creating local variable `parameters`.

But you have other problem. `parameters` doesn't exist at start. You create it in `get()`. But if you click second button before you use first button (which runs `get()`) then it will not create variable `parameters` and second button can't find variable `parameters`.

It is good rule to create variable at start with some default value - ie. with empty list.

```
import tkinter as tk
import fractions

# --- classes --

class ScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, vertical=True, horizontal=False):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # canvas for inner frame
        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self._canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news') # changed

        # create right scrollbar and connect to canvas Y
        self._vertical_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self._canvas.yview)
        if vertical:
            self._vertical_bar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self._canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self._vertical_bar.set)

        # create bottom scrollbar and connect to canvas X
        self._horizontal_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', command=self._canvas.xview)
        if horizontal:
            self._horizontal_bar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
        self._canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self._horizontal_bar.set)

        # inner frame for widgets
        self.inner = tk.Frame(self._canvas)
        self._window = self._canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.inner, anchor='nw')

        # autoresize inner frame
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # changed
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) # changed

        # resize when configure changed
        self.inner.bind('<Configure>', self.resize)

        # resize inner frame to canvas size
        self.resize_width = False
        self.resize_height = False
        self._canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.inner_resize)

    def resize(self, event=None): 
        self._canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._canvas.bbox('all'))

    def inner_resize(self, event):
        # resize inner frame to canvas size
        if self.resize_width:
            self._canvas.itemconfig(self._window, width=event.width)
        if self.resize_height:
            self._canvas.itemconfig(self._window, height=event.height)

# --- functions ---

def tests(parameters, root):
    if parameters:
        print('[before exit]', parameters[0])
    else:
        print('[before exit] WARNING: prameters not selected')
    root.destroy()
    #return None # every function returns `None` when you don't use `return`

def interface(root):
    #global parameters # not needed because `interface` doesn't assign value

    def get():
        global parameters # inform function to use external variable instead of creating local one
        parameters = []
        parameters.append(float(entries[0].get()))
        parameters.append(round(float(fractions.Fraction( eval( entries[1].get()) )), 7))

    # create scrolled frame
    sf = ScrolledFrame(root, True, True)
    sf.pack(fill='both', expand=True) # resize with window

    entries = []

    tk.Label(sf.inner, text="a").grid(row=2, sticky='w')
    entry = tk.Entry(sf.inner)
    entries.append(entry)
    entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

    tk.Label(sf.inner, text="b").grid(row=3, sticky='w')
    entry = tk.Entry(sf.inner)
    entries.append(entry)
    entry.grid(row=3, column=1)

    bouton_Valider = tk.Button(sf.inner, text="Valider les paramètres", fg="blue", command=get)
    bouton_Valider.grid(row=4, column=1)

    bouton_Executer = tk.Button(sf.inner, text="Exécuter le programme", fg="red", command=lambda: tests(parameters, root))
    bouton_Executer.grid(row=5, column=1)

    root.mainloop() 

# --- main ---

# create global variable with default value - so it will exists from beginning
parameters = []

root = tk.Tk()
interface(root)

if parameters:
    print('[after exit]', parameters)
else:
    print('[after exit] WARNING: prameters not selected')
```

Comment: Thanks you! What is the utility of the lines with '[before exit]' and '[after exit]'

Comment: You used `return parameters` after `mainloop()` so I add `before` / `after` to show that this variable will keep value after mainloop (after closing window). After `mainloop` you couldn't get value from widgets (`Entry`/`Label`)` or `StringVar`/`IntVar` because they don't exist after closing window.